# Ref and Selector on view

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a controller which has a reference defined this way :

```
refs : { title_Bar : '#title_Bar'},
```

When I had only one title bar in my main view with the itemId set to title_Bar, it worked fined.

Now that I have 2 title bar with the same item id, it seems that only one is updated?

Is that supposed to be that way or what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your selector is not specific enough.

itemId is unique within a given component, that you do not specify here in your selector. 
id is unique for the entire application (although I would recommend to use them carefully as you can sometimes by mistakes use it twice. It's bad because Sencha uses this id to render html and use your id as the id of the html tag. Hence if you specify it twice, one of the two component will not render.

Solution: 
If you have two different pages defined (each with one title bar, then you would have something like:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.page1', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'page1',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'title_bar'
        }
    ]
    ....
});

Ext.define('MyApp.view.page2', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'page2',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            itemId: 'title_bar'
        }
    ]
    ....
});
```

Having this, you can now access you bar titles using the following selectors:

```
refs: {
    barOne: 'page1 #title_bar',
    barTwo: 'page1 #title_bar'
}
```

You can of course nest itemId and read [further more here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/guide/controllers)

Comment: I see and quite frankly I am not suprise with what the sencha team did there -_-'. This framework is simply broken.

Comment: If You want you can replace "itemId" with "id" making sure on your own that you assign only unique "id" and then your selector will be a lot easier. 
I fancy this system to be honest.

Comment: I actually decided to never use id in my project, has it is sure to cause issues, only itemId since those are easier to maintain

Answer (score 0):

HTML Ids are unique.

You should only have one `#title_Bar` or otherwise change your Ids to classes and change your selector to `.title_bar`.

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure to follow what you explained, I'm using ST framework, and well i never set any HTML IDs directly? I was talking about my view object which has a ItemId property ^^